# Encrypting in a web worker make Safari crash with error 0x00000006

Tags: javascript, encryption, safari, web-worker, cryptojs

I'm trying to encrypt a password in a Web Worker using CryptoJS, but this makes (ONLY) Safari to crash with this error:

```
Error code:      0x00000006
```

The encryption works fine without the worker but this will make the app to freeze until the encryption is done (2-6 seconds).

Any ideas how I can solve this problem?

Comment: Can't really help you, but could you add the relevant part of code where you call the encryption to the question? And maybe also add the version of Safari, it can be a browser bug. You might also want to contact authors of the lib directly and then post here if you get an answer.

Comment: As far as I know there's ONLY vanilla JS possible in the worker. No JS lib of any kind can be used. I'm not familiar with CryptoJS but I assume it's a library.